# QRS detection algorithm

Tags: python

[QRS detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxBpP.jpg)

Hi, the image shows a QRS detection algorithm. I am trying to write the code in python.I have applied np.diff to compute the first and second derivatives. However, I am unable to compute

Yz(n) = 1.3Yo(n) + 1.1Yi(n)

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow =) There are many different frameworks used for machine learning. If you are more specific about what you need and what you already have more people may be able of helping you. Check here for how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you have the first and second derivate as functions (`y0(n)` and `y1(n)`) and you refer to the last line (`y2(n)=1.3*y0(n)+1.1*y1(n)`), then i don't see the problem in specifying this rather simple arithmetic operation:

```py
def y2(n): 
    return 1.3*y0(n)+1.1*y1(n)
```

if you just calculate for a specific n, then its even easier with `1.3*y0+1.1*y1`.

Update: For lists, this looks something like this:

```py
import random

# number of samples
N = 100

# random samples
random.seed(1)
x = [random.randint(1,100) for i in range(0,N)]

# let first 2/4 values be undefined for simpler access over index
y0 = [float("NaN") for i in range (0, 2)] + [abs(x[i]-x[i-2]) for i in range(2, N)]
y1 = [float("NaN") for i in range (0, 4)] + [abs(x[i]-2*x[i-2]+x[i-4]) for i in range(4, N)]
y2 = [float("NaN") for i in range (0, 4)] + [1.3*y0[i] + 1.1*y1[i] for i in range(4,N)]

print(y2)
```

Comment: Hi.Thanks for the help. I tried it but there seems to be a problem with computation of dot product with the size of y0 and y1 being an array of 1998 elements each.                             this is the error i shows---                                                                                            operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1998,) (1997,)

Comment: so you have a list of N=2000 values for x(i), where the index is i and the value in the list is x(i). and you want to get a list of N-4=1996 values for y2(i+4), (cant calculate for y2(0) - y2(4) since x(-4) is not defined), is this correct?

Comment: added a code snippet to show how to do it with lists (first 4 values will be undefined using the formula you shared)